# msys and tdm-gcc: configure error - cannot run C compiled programs

Tags: c++, gcc, msys

so I'm trying to compile a preexisting C++ project with msys and tdm-gcc in Windows. I have done this successfully by installing tdm-gcc (latest version) via the installer, editing MinGW/msys/1.0/etc/fstab to give my tdm-gcc install as the mount location, then running msys to call the configure script, and make. 
However, for this project I need to use an old version of tdm-gcc (4.6.1-tdm64-1) for binary compatibility. So I installed the required packages from the tdm-gcc sourceforge site (gcc core, gcc c++, binutils, mingw64-runtime, mingw32-make, libintl, libiconv, all of the version the readme says to use with 4.6.1), extracted to a new directory, and edited fstab to point to their location. Now while executing the configure I get this error: cannot run C compiled programs. The config file reads:

```
[omitted]

configure:3436: $? = 0
configure:3425: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\TDM-GCC-4.6.1-64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/tdm-gcc-4.6.1-64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/gcc-4.6.1/configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable- targets=all --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --with-gnu-ld --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-pkgversion=tdm64-1 --with-bugurl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.1 (tdm64-1) 
configure:3436: $? = 0
configure:3425: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3436: $? = 1
configure:3425: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized option '-qversion'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3436: $? = 1

configure:3456: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3478: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3482: $? = 0
configure:3530: result: yes
configure:3533: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3535: result: a.exe
configure:3541: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3548: gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3552: $? = 0
configure:3574: result: .exe
configure:3596: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3604: gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3608: $? = 0
configure:3615: ./conftest.exe
./configure: line 3617: ./conftest.exe: Bad file number
configure:3619: $? = 126
configure:3626: error: in `/c/jagswm':
configure:3628: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details

[omitted]
```

I've tried adding the tdm-gcc bin to my path, although I don't think that should matter if fstab is set. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your antivirus.
Worked for me while compiling GStreamer, probably because Avast was deleting the a.exe file.

Source: http://wiki.openttd.org/Compiling_on_Windows_using_MinGW#Compilation_and_installation_of_the_required_packages